# Excel is not responding after plotting chart by vba

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I have written a simple vba for plotting 6000 data point with the following code

```
Sub MbufferPlot()

'plot time history of 500 and 630Hz with 6000 time data points

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    ThisWorkbook.Date1904 = False

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cht As ChartObject

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("C135:HVV136")
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=180, Width:=800, Top:=1300, Height:=300)

    With cht.Chart

        .SetSourceData Source:=rng
        .ChartType = xlLine
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = "0th spacing time history"
        .SetElement (msoElementLegendBottom)
        .Axes(xlCategory).AxisBetweenCategories = False
        .Axes(xlCategory).TickLabelSpacing = 200
        .Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "General"
        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "500Hz"
        .SeriesCollection(2).Name = "630Hz"

    End With

    Set rng = Nothing
    Set cht = Nothing
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    ThisWorkbook.Date1904 = True

End Sub
```

After 1 to 3 successful running, the excel becomes not responding. The task manager shows my excel with very high memory and power usage. Could anyone please tell me why my code can't run smoothly?

Comment: Does this happen as well when you create that chart manually? • Turning off calculation and turning it on again will force a entire re-calculation of the sheets. If you have a lot of formulas that will take a bunch of time. • Go through your code step by step using F8 to see which line of code causes the issue to hang Excel. • Excel haning usually means it is still calculating. • With some test data in a brand new file I could not reproduce the issue with your code. The code in general works perfectly. So the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: I found that the vba code start to not responding when it stays at the line below

~Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=180, Width:=800, Top:=1300, Height:=300)~
That means the code above this line starts having problem
But what's the problem there?
Is Activesheet not a good call for plotting chart in multiple worksheets?

Comment: I have no issue with your code and cannot reproduce it. Try to copy your data you need for the chart into a brand new workbook and copy the code as well. It should run perfectly. There is something else wrong probably, the code you showed is ok.

Comment: Remove the `Application.Calculation =` in the beginning and the end and see if it gets better.

Comment: does workbook size a problem to run vba? coz my workbook cost around 100-300MB memory and it costs about 500MB RAM when opening without running any vba

Comment: The memory limit of Excel (32 bit) is 2 GB (but that is reached before you can see it in the task manager). If you reach that limit usually Excel quits with reporting "out of memory" error or just crashes (force close). • You can test 64 bit version to make sure this is not your issue (I tested it using 64 bit Excel).

Comment: I comment out the `Application.Calculation =` and successfully plot 3 worksheets with vba by using f8. However, when i use f5 to plot a new worksheet, it starts not responding again

Comment: I checked and the excel i am using is also 64 bits. Maybe copy the existing data to a new workbook is a good idea

Comment: Why waste your time with all of those application/workbook properties (EnableEvents, AskToUpdateLinks, DisplayAlerts, Date1904)?

Comment: becoz i hv no idea those application has any relationship with the not responding issue